# Finding / creating harmonic functions with given criteria

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Find a function $u$ harmonic on $\{Im(z)>0, Re(z)>0\}$ with boundary values $0$ on $\{Im(z)>0, Re(z)=0\}$ and 1 on $\{Im(z) = 0, Re(z) > 0 \}$.

How does one go about this? My professor literally wrote:

"$u(z) = 1 - \frac{2}{\pi} Arg(z)$ works"

Any idea how to tackle this?